# Replace special characters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How to replace '$txt$' in javascript.I want to replace all occurrences in the string

It's what i tried

```
if (html.indexOf('$txt$') > -1) {
    html = html.replace(/$txt$/ig, '<input type=text></input>');
}
```

but it won't replace the string.What's my mistake.Please help me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

all you need to do is escape the $ sign since it has a meaning in a regular expression. Change it to

```
html = html.replace(/\$txt\$/ig, '<input type="text" />');
```

and it should be fine :)

edit: $ means end of line in a regular expression :)

Answer (score 0):

html = html.replace(/[$]txt[$]/ig, '');  use this

Answer (score 0):

You're replacing using [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html), and `$` is a regular expression reserved special character for end of line/string.

You need to escape the `$` by preceding it with a backward slash `\` to make it hit its literal character:

```
if (html.indexOf('$txt$') > -1) {
    html = html.replace(/\$txt\$/ig, '<input type=text></input>');
}
```

Comment: that's a backward slash, what is used to escape a speial character.